# How to display a CheckBoxList on selectedIndexChange action of a DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist, autopostback

I  have a **CheckBoxList** which displays data **on a selectedIndexChange action** of a DropDownList. Everything works correctly. I  have checked it in a button click event. But **When I use it with a selectedIndexChange nothing happens**. I dont get any error or exception. I have enabled AutoPostBack property too.

Here is my code

```html
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstKPI" style="width:auto; height:auto;   float:right" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

code of the CheckBoxList

```
public void loadCheckBoxPanel()
{
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string cName = ddlCompName.SelectedValue.ToString();
        ds = db.fillCheck(cName);

        chklstKPI.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        chklstKPI.DataTextField = "COMPETITION_KPI";
        chklstKPI.DataValueField = "COMPETITION_KPI";
        chklstKPI.DataBind();

}
```

I didn't add the query.

Comment: Does it actually send a post? I don't think you have bound `loadCheckBoxPanel` to the `SelectedIndexChanged` yet.

Comment: I have called the method inside a SelectedIndexChanged action

Comment: Then you should have `OnSelectedIndexChanged="MethodNameHere"` in your code as part of the CheckBoxList's definition, and I don't see it. Something like: `<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstKPI" Style="width: auto; height: auto; float: right" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chklstKPI_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:CheckBoxList>`

Comment: CheckBoxList doesn't have any action. Its within a DropDownList's OnSelectedIndexChanged action

Comment: Gotcha. You didn't share any code regarding your DropDownList.

Comment: Ok, i will edit the question and add the code of the dropdownlist too.

Comment: @ Hanlet Escano I think the problem is with the DropDownList. There is no SelectedIndexChanged property.

Comment: OnSelectedIndexChanged is not a property, it should be an event. Click on the property window and you should see a thunder looking icon. Click there and you should see all of the available events for your control.

Comment: Please update your code with your dropdownlist code and its event which is showing the checkboxlist. IMO problem should be there like @hanlet said

Comment: I found the mistake. OnSelectedIndexChanged wasn't in the dropdownlist's properties though i created it. Therefore i created it again. Now it works as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isLoading = true;    
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         chklstKPI.Style.Visibility="hidden";
         chklstKPI.Style.Displpay="none";
         myList.OnSelectedIndexChanged += performCheckBoxAction;
         myList.SelectedIndex=0;
         isLoading = false;               
    }
protected void performCheckBoxAction(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(isLoading==false){
        isLoading = true;
        chklstKPI.Style.visibility="visible";
        chklistKPI.Style.display="show";
        isLoading=false;
    }
}
```